# ArrayAdater getView "caching" convertView

Tags: android

I have a problem when "caching" my `convertView` in my Custom Adapters `getView` method. When using "caching" like

```
if (convertView == null) ...
```

my `verifiedView` is sometimes displayed even when the user is not verified. When removing the if construct and just use `row = convertView;` everything works as expected. Any idea how to fix this?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    View row;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }

     UserProfile user = users.get(position);
    // get views
    TextView usernameView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.username);
    ImageView avatarView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    ImageView verifiedView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.verified);

    // check if user has an custom avatar
    if (!user.getAvatar().isEmpty()) {
        // now check if we already downloaded the avatar
        InputStream is = AvatarHandler.getAvatar(this.context, user.getID());
        if (is != null) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            System.out.println("Avatar already downloaded.");
            avatarView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }
    else {
        // set default avatar
        avatarView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);         
    }

    // set username
    usernameView.setText(user.getName());

    // set verified
    if (user.isVerified())
        verifiedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return row;
}
```

Comment: You only set the view visible when verified, but you do not make it hidden when not.

Comment: I set the view invisible in the XML via `android:visibility="gone"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hide `verifiedView` when the user is not verified:

```
// set verified
if (user.isVerified()) {
        verifiedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
        verifiedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary when I already hide it in the XML? Edit: Well it seems to work though.

Comment: Depends if the verified state changes. Anyway it is a good practice to do as @erakitin proposed. Try it and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Yes, it's necessary. The view is being reused from another row that went off-screen, and in which you set its visibility to VISIBLE.